# How do I fetch a specific result from mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I'm still new to reactjs and mongodb.I am trying to fetch a single record of user and display it on the page. But so far I got no output. I want the page to immediately display the result on load

This is my profile.js:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const user = localStorage.getItem('user')
    const userObject = {
        username: localStorage.getItem('user'),
    };
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users/getUser', userObject)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("hi"+res.data)
            const userinfo = res.data
            
            this.setState({
                name: userinfo.name,
                username: res.username,
                email: res.email,
                password: res.password,
                company: res.company,
                position: res.position

            })
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

and this is my backend(user.js):

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
express = require('express'),
router = express.Router(),
user = require('../models/user-schema');

router.post('/getUser', async (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body.username)
const User = await user.find({ name: req.body.username })

if (!User) {
    return { status: 'error', error: 'Invalid Login' }
}else {
    return res.json({
        status: 'ok',
        name: User.name,
        username: User.username,
        email: User.email,
        company:User.company,
        position: User.position,
        level: User.userLevel
    })
}
```

})

Comment: If you want to get one user data use the `findOne` method. The `find` method in your code returns an array of matching users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.find({ name: req.body.username })` is going to return an array. So in the code below, all those fields such `User.name ,  User.username, User.email` etc are going to be undefined since `User = [{name:xxx,username:xxx }]`

```
res.json({
        status: 'ok',
        name: User.name, // undefined
        username: User.username, // undefined
        email: User.email, // undefined
        company:User.company, // undefined
        position: User.position,// undefined
        level: User.userLevel // undefined
    })
```

You should use `user.findOne({ name: req.body.username })` which will return a single object and then you can access the properties.

Additionally (Personal preference) , one might have multiple users with the same username. To make sure you're retrieving the correct docuemnt, rather use `findById()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this `find({})` you can use `findOne({})` cause `find({})` going to return an array but your are expecting an object that the the problem

Answer (score 1):

Use **findOne()** instead of **find()** method, **find()** method returns an array of objects and **findOne()** method return a single particular object.

```
const User = await user.findOne({ name: req.body.username })
```

and you can pass specific filed which you want to get like

```
let User = await user.findOne({ name: req.body.username },{username:1, email:1, company:1, position:1, level:1});

if(!User){
  return res.status(404).json({ status: 'error', error: 'Invalid Login' });
} else {
  return res.status(404).json({status:"ok", ...User});
}
```